# Create a user on mysql database at RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I tried to create a user to grant access to a database hosted at amazon `RDS`, the user was created, but I can't access to the database that it has allowed to manage, here's the code I used:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db.* TO 'admin'@'my.rds.domain' IDENTIFIED BY
'xxxyyyzzz';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;
```

I ran that from my mysql client — `DataGrid`–  also, I verified that the user was created using:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

And effectively, the user is listed.

Is there any special configuration I have to make at RDS console, or what?

Comment: Try to change hostname in mysql.user for admin user from 'my.rds.domain' to '%' temporarily. Flush privileges and try accessing again with admin user. Does that work? If it does, we can suggest other steps.

Comment: It worked that way, but what does '%' mean @zedfoxus?

Comment: Let me add an answer describing that. Hang on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `GRANT` command, `'admin'@'my.rds.domain'` means that admin user connecting from my.rds.domain host is granted all privileges on my_db's all objects.

If this admin user attempts to log on from hostname abc.microsoft.com, no access will be given. If the hostname is not understood by MySQL server, it uses IP to form a user@hostname (e.g. 'admin'@'88.99.11.22'). If that entry is not in mysql.users table access will be denied.

If we use 'admin'@'%', it means that admin user logging in from any system is granted the rights. So when you changed hostname to %, access was granted. For better security, if you know that the user is going to log on from a particular IP or hostname only, it would be best to do like you did ('admin'@'hostname').

Comment: Yes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html - scroll down to Account Names and Passwords. You will see the description of wildcard characters there. For foreign key constraints, feel free to open a new question and let me know the link to it. If no good answers are received for your new question, I'll try to help out

Comment: Already solved, it was a typo in the migration script... thnks